# Уместен ли здесь союз "что"?

Tags: грамматика

Какой вариант более верный: "человек живёт надеждой отыскать своё счастье" или "человек живёт надеждой, что отыщет своё счастье"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый лучше.

"*Что отыщет своё счастье*" звучит конкретно, так, что известно, что это за счастье, и именно его надо отыскать, а это же не так.

Похожий пример:
*Человек живёт надеждой, что отыщет свою собаку.* || Здесь инфинитив (*отыскать свою собаку*) уже не звучит, потому что конкретно известен объект поисков.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ну вот, опять. Там не "так что" (оно вообще по смыслу не подходит), а "звучит так".

Comment: Прости! Но оформление с лесом запятых всё равно дурацкое.

Comment: Просто мне надо было куда-то всунуть слово "конкретно".

Answer (score 0):

Оба эти варианта грамматически верны и не имеют семантических или стилистических отличий (может быть, очень-очень-очень тонкие стилистические).

Comment: Мой ответ, что они оба одинаковы.

Comment: Как бы вы написали?

Comment: Что первое пришло бы в голову.